# How should I edit this code to make an invert blur effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

This is the code I copied from a blog

[here is the link cause I can't seem to make it work here](http://pastebin.com/8DS3fMG5)

I want it to be **blurred** at first then at hover the blur should disappear.

Here is my test blog > (SOVED)

If you hover on the thumbnail of a post you can see it is blurring,
so, what I wanted is - I want that thumbnail to be blurred at first, and when hovered the blur should disappear.

please help. thanks

Comment: Please post some actual code we can work with to help answer you question. Are you wanting to blur an image, an entire page, a portion of a page?

Comment: i linked the code through pastebin - that's actually a link to the code.
and btw, its "-3px" there... i changed it. it should be "3px" (not negative three)

Comment: I see that you linked a rather large amount of CSS code through pastebin, but that still doesn't explain what you are trying to do. Give us some more information as to what you are trying to blur, what you have tried already, and any other relevant information...

Comment: @StannStee Be specific and mention which thing you want to blur and disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating your original question to clarify what you were actually asking. After looking at your blog I realise what you are trying to achieve.

What you need is a basic blur filter to toggle off when the image is hovered, this can be achieved using the CSS `filter: blur();` property in addition to a simple `:hover` selector.

In the default styling of the image, the blur filter should be set to blur by default, therefore the CSS will be:

```
.image {
  filter: blur(3px);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

*To note: the `transition` property above gives the blur a 'fade' effect.*

When you hover over the image (`.image:hover`), the filter should change so that there is no longer a blur present on the image, therefore the CSS will be:

```
.image:hover {
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

If you want to read more on the CSS Filter Blur effect, [have a look here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp).

***I have compiled the above into a JSFiddle Example for you to utilise to hopefully explain my answer slightly better: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/54qe6dLx/1/)***

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler code that as your desired effect:

```css
figure {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 20em;
}
figure .image {
  background: transparent url("") center/0 0 no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
figure .image:before,
figure .image:after {
  background-image: inherit;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
figure .image:before {
  padding-top: 66.6667%; // define image ratio. Here 3:2
}
figure .image:after {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: filter 200ms;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
figure figcaption {
  padding: 1em;
}
figure:hover .image:after {
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/900/600/brazil,rio)"></div>
  <figcaption>Some caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for

```
.gallery-wrapper:hover img.gallry_img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-filter: blur(-3px);
    filter: blur(-3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(-3px);
}
```

And replace it with the next

```
.gallery-wrapper img.gallry_img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-filter: blur(-3px);
    filter: blur(-3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(-3px);
}
.gallery-wrapper:hover img.gallry_img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
}
```